# Image from Firebase storage to Recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to put Images from Firebase storage to Recycler view based on Document ID. When I explicitly pass the uri to shop object then that picture get displayed. 
But it is not taking image from Firebase storage.Don't know why it is not working. All the other things are working fine.

Here is my
**Data Model**

```
package com.ufdstudios.ezyq;

import android.net.Uri;

public class Shops {

    private String ShopId;
    private String Name;
    private String Status;
    private Uri uri;

    public Shops(){}

    public Shops(String Name,String Status,Uri uri)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Status = Status;
        this.uri = uri;
    }


    public String getshopName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getShopStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setshopName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public void setShopStatus(String Status) {
        this.Status = Status;
    }

    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String getShopId() {
        return ShopId;
    }

    public void setShopId(String shopId) {
        ShopId = shopId;
    }
}
```

**Custom Adapter**

```
package com.ufdstudios.ezyq;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class ShopsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopsListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<Shops> shopsList;


    public ShopsListAdapter(List<Shops> shopsList)
    {
        this.shopsList = shopsList;
    }

    // sepcifying lauout style of list
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.shop_list_layout, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return shopsList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View mView;
        // views here
        public TextView tv_shop_id;
        public TextView tv_shop_name;
        public TextView tv_shop_status;
        public ImageView iv_shop_logo;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView =itemView;

            // linking views here
            tv_shop_id = mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop_id);
            tv_shop_status = mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop_status);
            tv_shop_name = mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop_name);
            iv_shop_logo = mView.findViewById(R.id.iv_shop_logo);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // setting values here
        holder.tv_shop_status.setText(shopsList.get(position).getShopStatus());
        holder.tv_shop_id.setText(shopsList.get(position).getShopId());
        holder.tv_shop_name.setText(shopsList.get(position).getshopName());
        // using picaso library to populate image from uri
        Picasso.get().load(shopsList.get(position).getUri()).into(holder.iv_shop_logo);


    }

}
```

**Fragment**

```
//creating List View
         shopList =  new ArrayList<>();
// adaper
         shopsListAdapter = new ShopsListAdapter(shopList);
// setting up recycler view
        recycler_view = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recycler_view.setAdapter(shopsListAdapter);

        dbRef.collection("shop").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();
                   List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = querySnapshot.getDocuments();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : docs) {

                        final Shops shops = new Shops();
                        shops.setshopName(document.get("Name").toString());
                        shops.setShopStatus(document.get("Status").toString());
                        shops.setShopId(document.getId());

                        String shop_id = document.getId();
                        storageRef = storage.getReference().child("/shops_logo/" + shop_id +".png"); // get reference of shop_id named logo
                        storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                // puttindg logo from Firebase Storage to Image View
                               shops.setUri(uri);
                            }
                        });

                        // adding to list
                        shopList.add(shops);
                        // change event listener for in databaess
                        shopsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

Tired this way too. But problem still remains intact:

```
 dbRef.collection("shop").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(final QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if(e!=null)
            {
                // eror hangle here
            }
            for(DocumentChange doc: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
            {
                if(doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    // getting data in Objects
                   // Shops shops = doc.getDocument().toObject(Shops.class);
                    final Shops shops = new Shops();
                    shops.setshopName(doc.getDocument().get("Name").toString());
                    shops.setShopStatus(doc.getDocument().get("Status").toString());

                    String shop_id = doc.getDocument().getId(); // geting shop id
                    shops.setShopId(shop_id);
                    //getting logo from databae
                    // using that shop id to let shops logo

                  //  shops.setUri(Uri.parse("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYXVTbxmHQuOogxDeNx7U6z7neHX4kOQPZEBLG5nzQZoMMhkFN"));
                    storageRef = storage.getReference().child("/shops_logo/" + shop_id +".png"); // get reference of shop_id named logo

                    storageRef.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                                                                      @Override
                                                                      public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
                                                                          shops.setUri(storageMetadata.getDownloadUrl());
                                                                      }
                                                                  });


                            // adding to list
                            shopList.add(shops);
                    // change event listener for in databaess
                    shopsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**Database SnapShot:**
[image: Database]

[image: Storeage]

Any Solution? Thanks

Comment: add uri to your collection  and simple get that instead of using extra calls.?

Comment: Answer I posted that may solve your issue, but ideal way of doing is what  @AtifAbbAsi has mentioned.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is you are making an extra asynchronous call to get the image uri, but `Shop` object is getting added into the list before loading of image uri complete.

Replace your for loop as below

```
for (DocumentSnapshot document : docs) {

    final Shops shops = new Shops();
    shops.setshopName(document.get("Name").toString());
    shops.setShopStatus(document.get("Status").toString());
    shops.setShopId(document.getId());

    String shop_id = document.getId();
    storageRef = storage.getReference().child("/shops_logo/" + shop_id +".png"); // get reference of shop_id named logo
    storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // puttindg logo from Firebase Storage to Image View
           shops.setUri(uri);// adding to list
           shopList.add(shops);
           // change event listener for in databaess
           shopsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
           shopList.add(shops);
           // change event listener for in databaess
           shopsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```